# Using R in Java application on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, r, tomcat, rjava

This is a follow up to one of [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977723/setup-r-and-java-application-on-osx-10-7-2) about using R with JAVA on a Mac. My application depends on R to run. I've got Java installed, java version "1.6.0_37". I've got "R" installed, R version 2.15.1. Now I need JRI which is included in [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/index.html).

Inside of R I've run the following

> install.packages('rJava',,'http://www.rforge.net/')

This was the output:

```
install.packages('rJava',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
trying URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.15/rJava_0.9-4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 506489 bytes (494 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 494 Kb


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/gz/1jwm65h12132yq8_1wdsl9cr0000gn/T//RtmpGHpTYR/downloaded_packages
```

Where do I go from here?

When starting tomcat I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jri in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
        at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:9)
        at com.visibleequity.servlets.VisibleEquityServlet.init(VisibleEquityServlet.java:55)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1274)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5320)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**UPDATE 2/15/13 After trying to set Environment Variables...**

My PATH:

```
    DAVIDs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ dave$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/libexec/java_home:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rJava/jri
```

[image: environment variables]

[image: JAVA_HOME location]

[image: R_HOME and JRI location]

**Still getting the error above.**

Comment: As the error tells you, you have to setup the environment properly including `java.library.path` and many other things (`R_HOME` etc.). You can find out the location of JRI by running `system.file("jri", package="rJava")` in `R`.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek Ok so I've set up R_HOME & JAVA_HOME...Normally on windows this would be our setup.                 Path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%R_HOME%\bin;%R_HOME%\library\rJava\jri;

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17
R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.10.0                                        Where/How do I access the path?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the environment variables are there for the user Tomcat is running as.

Comment: you're right. Using tomcat I haven't had to set JAVA_HOME or R_HOME on my Mac until now so I'm not clear on how to do this. (I've done it on windows a ton). After searching Google and Stack it appears with Mountain Lion there have been some changes in where/how to set these so I found a utility where you can set the env variables http://diaryproducts.net/EnvPane (So I've set JAVA_HOME and R_HOME). Now where do I edit the path as I usually do in Windows? (See my comment above)

Comment: PATH env variable. All uppercase.

Comment: Larry, see my edits to my question. I thought I had edited the PATH but I must be mapping the variable wrong. See my updates above (with picures)....thanks for the help.

Comment: When referring to other env variables on Unix/OSX, use $R_HOME (the $ in front is the key). It is like %R_HOME% on Windows.

Comment: I've updated my path above. I made your suggested edit...but I'm still getting the error when I try to start tomcat

Comment: look at http://www.rforge.net/JRI/ in the FAQ, it has some env variables, and system properties that might help...